# How to pip install bcrypt on Azure webapp?

Tags: python, azure, pip, virtualenv, bcrypt

Disclosure : First time Azure experience

I am deploying a Flask app to Azure Webapp. All deployment steps are fine till I hit the bcrypt package installation and it fails.

After much research based on error log output, I found out that I might need to install bcrypt using wheelhouse (*.WHL)

I downloaded the below files from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.0)

- bcrypt-3.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- bcrypt-3.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

and I copied them to `D:\home\site\repository\wheelhouse`

Then, I activated the virtualenv through KUDU and I run this command:

```
d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links d:\home\site\repository\wheelhouse
```

I get no messages or any log output.  When I run a `pip freeze > tmp.txt` I get a blank file.

But when I run `d:\python27\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links d:\home\site\repository\wheelhouse`

It starts installing the packages until it gets to bcrypt and it errs out with this message:

> Skipping bcrypt-3.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl because it is not compatible with
>   this Python

Which is a confusing message because the wheel is for Python 2.7

Since my Flask app works fine on both my Linux and Windows dev machines, I went ahead and created my own brypt wheel file in my Windows computer which runs the same Python version on Azure.  I uploaded the new `.whl`, redid the steps above and I still get the same error message

Extra notes:

- python -V on Azure console returns 2.7.8
- python -V while virtualenv is activated also returns 2.7.8
- Azure portal > Application Settings shows "Python version 2.7" and "Platform 32bits".
- After deployment, all packages in requirements.txt are installed except bcrypt.
- Visiting the web page gives a 500 error (which i expect due to missing lib)
- I removed the virtualenv and GIT pushed the repo with `--find-links wheelhouse` at the top of requirements.txt as stated [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#_build-wheels-requires-windows).
  However, I get a `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error. That's why I m trying to manually install via wheel
- I deleted the whole virtualenv, uploaded wheel files for all required packages to \repository\wheelhouse and added `--no-index` to my pip install command. Everything gets installed except bcrypt.
- I tried `bcrypt==3.1.1`, `bcrypt==3.1.0` and just `bcrypt` without specifying the version and it doesnt make any difference.

I ran out of ideas.  Anyone knows what's wrong? How do I go about installing bcrypt on Azure webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the Flask app working on Azure Webapps.
Unfortunately, I couldn't do it using my usual dev tools.

**Solution**:

- I created a VirtualEnv in Visual Studio using my `requirements.txt` file
- Moved my Flask code to Visual Studio
- Click on Publish to Azure Webapps

It does what it does and once completed, you may still get a 500 error.
 If that is the case, use KUDU and take a look at your `web.config` file and modify the `WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER` value to match your Flask app name.

This is the only way I was able to get `bcrypt` to install correctly for my Flask app to work.  I hope this saves someone valuable time.

That's all folks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have tried using `easy_install` to install dependencies that failed to do so by `pip`. What I did was :

1. Go into KUDU debug Console. This is listed under Development Tools
2. Try executing `env\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt`
3. For every failed dependency (as bcrypt), try and install it through `env\scripts\easy_install bcrypt==3.1.0`

You could also try and automate this by editing the `deploy.cmd` file. Such that at any point that `pip` fails, `easy_install` is executed

Comment: Nope, this does not work for me. Still the same error